# Error Splitting Argument List FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to join 3 .mp4 files from my gopro using FFMPEG using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -1 input.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

I get the following Error:

```
PS C:\Users\x\desktop> ffmpeg -f concat -1 input.txt -c copy output.mp4
ffmpeg version git-2020-05-22-38490cb Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200513
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 46.100 / 56. 46.100
  libavcodec     58. 86.101 / 58. 86.101
  libavformat    58. 43.100 / 58. 43.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 82.100 /  7. 82.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Unrecognized option '1'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have very little experience with using this kind of stuff however it seems to be my best option for what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Likely your only error is `-1` where it should be `-i`.

Just for clarity, I'll include the steps to assure the command will work.

For MP4 files, you will need to follow the instructions for streaming files as shown [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer)

First, make your `input.txt` file with something like the following command:

```
for f in ./*.mp4; do echo "file '$f'" >> input.txt; done
```

Edit that `input.txt` file to make sure you have the videos you want in the correct order.

The command to do the concatenation will then be

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i input.txt -c copy output.mp4
```